# Formula to highlight columns if checkbox checked - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

In the image below - If someone selects any checkbox in Column A (Forklift) - I would like that row of **C, D & E** to be highlighted in YELLOW & BOLD - as you see below.

I tried using the conditional formatting but realized I need a formula to run it - hence why I am asking.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Hey @TomSawkins, what have you tried in order to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply to range **C3:D**:

```
=$A3=TRUE
```